# I met a trouble about DatagramSocket

Tags: java

[image: error]

DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(12345);//here, 12345 is the port

```
    while (true) {
        byte[] bys = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(bys, bys.length);
        ds.receive(dp);

        String ip = dp.getAddress().getHostAddress();
        String s = new String(dp.getData(), 0, dp.getLength());
        System.out.println("from " + ip + " data is : " + s);
    }
```

why?

Comment: You appear to have a broken JDK there.  What version of Windows are you running on?

Comment: My version of Windows is windows 8.1. My version of JDK is 8u73.

Answer (score 0):

The `UnsatisfiedLinkException` you are getting is saying that there is a missing native code implementation for a method in the standard class libraries.  This is a "should not happen" problem.

The fact that you managed to get your code running from NetBeans but not Eclipse implies that something is broken in the Eclipse launcher configs or the like, rather than the JDK you are using.

- I would suggest trying to run the app from the command line too.
- To fix the Eclipse problem:

  - try deleting and recreating the launch config,
  - try checking that the selected JRE is correct, and
  - try a fresh install of Eclipse.

Comment: I get my code running from the command line, it is feasible. <br/>       but you suggested me to fix the Eclipse problem by deleting and recreating the launch config, i didn't set any launch config. Meanwhile, could you provide me with some method on how to check selected JRE is correct.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the api you have that the `UnsatisfiedLinkException` happens **only** when:

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate
>   native-language definition of a method declared native.

You need to look into which JVM you are running with eclipse. There shouldn't be a problem with your code or eclipse itself. It's just a JVM issue. It tries to find a method implementation by your system and it just doesn't find it. If you are running this on windows it could be a dll related problem. Maybe you need to update some driver or maybe the JVM so that it supports your current implementation in windows.